# Bootstrap 5 containers act different when they are inside a row

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

In Bootstrap 4.6 containers have 1320px max-width. This width same whether its inside a row or outside. However in Bootstrap 5 this is not the same and I couldn't find the reason.
IMAGES:
BT4 IMAGE:
[image: BT4 IMAGE] – SAME SITE BUT USING BT5:
[image: SAME SITE BUT USING BT5]

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I wanted a full-width bootstrap container with a limited width container to make a colorized navbar but the contents were going to be in the middle. I was using that bad method for this and everything was fine until I change bt4 to bt5. now I am using a nav tag instead of a container-fluid and a container to make things centered. My original question was "what is the difference between bt4 and bt5 because I've checked the docs they didn't mention this" but thanks to you I've researched bt more and seen the examples. so I'm using a proper way to do this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `container` inside the `row`, it should be a `col` instead, for every version of Bootstrap since v3

> Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding
> (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding
> is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins to ensure the
> content in your columns is visually aligned down the left side. Rows
> also support modifier classes to uniformly apply column sizing and
> gutter classes to change the spacing of your content.

Check container examples from Bootstrap 5 [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/grid/#containers)

A basic example taken from the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```